# How to solve AVD auto rotate screen issue in android 4.4.2?

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

When I use an AVD to run a simple app, I need to have a look at landscape view, after some search , I checked my "Auto rotate screen" setting in Settings->Display->Auto rotate screen, then I can rotate the window by click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, but the content in my app don't show as I expected.

I found there was a bug report about Android 2.3 AVD ([Issue 13189: Orientation does not change from landscape to portrait on Emulator on 2.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189)), but no body has resolved it by now.

Anyone can have some idea?

This is the problem:
portrait view:
[image]

landscape view:
[image]

This is my AVD Details:

[image]

This is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.SimpleFragment"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: "but the content in my app don't show as i expected." <-- what does this mean? The bug from Android 2.3 is specifically for Android 2.3 and should be found on 2.3, hence this is probably why they didn't fix the bug.
My Android 4.2.2 emulator is working fine when rotating from portrait to landscape and vice versa. Could you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I've post my AndroidManifest.xml file. thx.

Comment: @JiangZhanchang i am also having the same issue..

Comment: Not yet have idea now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to using  Genymotion Emulator instead or AVD. It has a rotate button between landscape and portrait